# Spring oAuth2 /token Google Assistant

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, actions-on-google

I have the following piece of code, which works perfectly for securing Amazon Alexa Account Linking. This was build by a colleague who is now offline (i'm pulling a nightshift).

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity

public class SkillRestConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private static final String AMAZON_ALEXA_TOKEN_EXCHANGE_ROLE = "AMAZON-ALEXA-TOKEN-EXCHANGE";
    private static final String TOKEN_EXCHANGE_CLIENT_ID_KEY = "TOKEN_EXCHANGE_CLIENT_ID";
    private static final String TOKEN_EXCHANGE_CLIENT_SECRET_KEY = "TOKEN_EXCHANGE_CLIENT_SECRET";

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobalSecurity(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
            .withUser(Environment.get(TOKEN_EXCHANGE_CLIENT_ID_KEY))
            .password(Environment.get(TOKEN_EXCHANGE_CLIENT_SECRET_KEY))
            .roles(AMAZON_ALEXA_TOKEN_EXCHANGE_ROLE);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable();

        // Allow basic authentication from Amazon
        http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/token").hasRole(AMAZON_ALEXA_TOKEN_EXCHANGE_ROLE)
            .and().httpBasic();
    }
}
```

However, i would like to extend that also to be usable for Google Account Linking. Google does not send a basic authentication header, in fact it doesn't send an authorization header at all, but passes the client_id and client_secret as POST data.

How can i make sure that that part is also 'authenticated' in the /token endpoint? e.g. support both of these authentication methods? If i get a POST request on /token where the client_id and client_secret match predefined environment variables, either via basic auth or in the POST data it should be allowed.

Is that as simple as adding the following code?

```
http.antMatchers("/token")
    .formLogin()
    .permitAll()
    .usernameParameter("client_id")
    .passwordParameter("client_secret");
```

and if so, should i put this after, or before the 'http.authorizeRequests()' call?

**edit:**
By doing some additional research, I think i need to create my own filter and authenticationprovider. The filter would extract the username and password from the request and set this on the securitycontext if i understand it correctly. This should only be done if there is no basic authentication header present and if the POST contains the right values. I think i can accomplish this with the following piece of code, by extending the UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken into ClientIdAndSecretAuthenticationToken.

```
@Override
public boolean supports(Class<?> authentication) {
    return (ClientIdAndSecretAuthenticationToken.class.isAssignableFrom(authentication));
}
```

and

```
http.antMatchers("/token")
    .addFilterBefore(clientIdAndSecretAuthenticationFilter, ClientIdAndSecretAuthenticationFilter.class)
    .authenticationProvider(clientIdAndSecretAuthenticationProvider)
```

am i warm here?

Comment: Can you just clarify - at which point in the token exchange is this?

Comment: it is after the authCode has been passed back to Google, when Google sends a request to my authentication server to exchange that temp token for a valid token and refresh token.